# changing quantity to list <object> in listbox checkout

Tags: c#, listbox

hi i have a program that is a Mediastore and i have 4 classes. Produkt: which is a class with a few variables that i use to add products to my List.

```
public class produkt
{
    public string Name;
    public string price;
    public string Serialnumber;
    public int kvantitet;

    public override string ToString() 
    { 
        return "ProduktNamn: " + Name + 
               " VaruNr: (" + Serialnumber + ") " + 
               "Pris: " + price + 
               " Kr" + " Kvantitet " +kvantitet; 
    }
```

LagerList : This class is static and is only used to store my List so that it can be acessed from diffrent forms.

```
public static class LagerList
{
    public static List<produkt> List = new List<produkt>();
```

then i have my Lager class which i use to add my products to my list and Listbox. This is done by having 3 textfields where i say what the Name,SerialNumber and Price of the object i created should have.

In this class i also have 2 more textfields and a button that make it possible to add a quantity of the selected listbox object of my product Class. if the item im trying to add a quantity to dosent exist i get a question if i wanna add that product and it adds that product to the list. if however the product allready exist its suposed to add the quantity with the selected amount from my textbox.

Then I have my Class Kassa which is a Form with 2 Listboxes. 
The first listbox share the same List as the one in my Lager class and the other listbox is the listbox which i use to take items from my produktlist and put it in my checkout "basket" then i am suposed to be able to choose one of these items from my checkout basket put the amount i want of that item into a textfield called KvantLEv and press the checkout button to be able to simulate a checkout and then this selected item's quantity is suposed to be lowerd by the specified amount and is to be removed from the checkoutlistbox but this aint working... 
this is my checkout function so far

```
private void cashout()
{

    int a = VaruKorg.Items.Count - 1;
    for (int i = a; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (VaruKorg.GetSelected(i))
        {
           // //checkKvant is the textfield of the specified amount i want my quantity             to be lowerd.   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where you setting produkt's initial quantity in cashout()?

Comment: In my class Lager i first create the product, then to add quantity to that item using a method so when i start project i first create the objects im gonna use then add quantity to them and then i go to my Kassa form and put them in the checkout listbox and its here i wanna be able to remove the specified quantity when i click the checkout button

Comment: I am later gonna add a CSV file  in which im gonna save all my objects to and also be able to upload them everytime project starts so i dont have to add them everythime i wanna try something

Comment: Right, but in this cashout() method you create a new produkt, you're not getting it from anywhere.

Comment: Yeah i know i realised it just after i posted it has no value since its a brand new produkt without any value. I edited my original post and fixed it but all i really need help with is how to lower my quantity variable of the selected item based on the value of the textbox.

Comment: Are you getting the produkt from VaruKorg.GetSelected?

Comment: yeh i use my add method to add that object to my listbox VaruKorg. so i simply wanna be able to pick an object from that list and reduce the  Kvantitet variable of that object with the amount specified with me textfield.

Comment: I could sent my entire code if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're using GetSelected() here for, but if VaruKorg contains the items in the basket, and you've added them from the original list (i.e. they are references), you could just do something like this:

```
private void cashout()
{
    if (VaruKorg.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
       ((produkt)VaruKorg.SelectedItem).kvantitet -= Int.Parse(sometextfield);
    }
}
```